# How to input args in cmd/sudo and use them in runtime? (Java)

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have this code:

```java
public class CalculatingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger();
        
        int valueA = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String operation = args[1];
        int valueB = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        if ("add".equals(operation)) {
            result.set(valueA + valueB);
        } else if ("subt".equals(operation)) {
            result.set(valueA - valueB);
        } else if ("mult".equals(operation)) {
            result.set(valueA * valueB);
        } else if ("div".equals(operation)) {
            result.set(valueA / valueB);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input");
        }

        System.out.println(result.get());
    }
}
```

I use IDEa terminal for these commands:

> javac CalculatingApp.java
>
> java CalculatingApp 5 add 10

But console output:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: CalculatingApp has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version
> of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Java -version:

> java version "1.8.0_51"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

**You may find other errors.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks the code is compiled by JAVA8, but ran by Java 13.

Try java -version in IDEA terminal to take a look the java version.

Comment: >java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: try to clean all the compiled classes and again?

Comment: Same problem when you running it by IDEA RUN?

Comment: I have no problem with the same programm without args, but how can I test this one without sudo?